# react-google-maps : Can't get bounds

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, react-google-maps

I have the following react component that loads a GoogleMap from 'react-google-maps' library. I'm following the documentation examples but I get undefined from getBounds() function. I think it is due to trying to get the bounds before map is fully loaded but can't find a solution.

```
@inject("map") @observer
export default class Map extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        const mapStore = this.props.map
        const GettingStartedGoogleMap = withGoogleMap(props => (
            <GoogleMap
                ref={props.onMapLoad}
                style={{
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                }}
                defaultOptions={{ styles: this.mapStyles }}
                defaultZoom={mapStore.zoom}
                defaultCenter={{ lat: mapStore.center.lat, lng: mapStore.center.lng }}>
                {
                    mapStore.markers.map(({ lat, lng }) => {
                        return <Marker
                            position={{ lat, lng }}
                            icon={{
                                url: require('../../images/marker.png')
                            }}
                        />
                    })
                }
            </GoogleMap>
        ))

        return (
            <GettingStartedGoogleMap
                style={{
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                }}
                onMapLoad={(googleMap) => {
                    console.log(googleMap.getBounds())
                }}
                containerElement={
                    <div style={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 70px)' }
                    } />
                }
                mapElement={
                    <div style={{ height: 'calc(100vh - 70px)' }} />
                } />
        )
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use 'onIdle' to make sure map is fully ready

`<GoogleMap
   ref={props.onMapLoad}
   ...
   onIdle={props.onMapIdle}
>
   ...
</GoogleMap>`

and

`<GettingStartedGoogleMap
   onMapIdle={ ()=> { console.log('map is ready') } }
   ...
/>`

Comment: So how to cal `getBounds` function here?